# Remove Help+Tips app

Tags: 8.0

Is there a way to remove the Help+Tips app that exists by default on WP8? When I long press the app in the list, there's no "Uninstall" option.

Is there a way to remove or hide this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your phone to WP8.1. The Help+Tips is removed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. I have all settings menus and found no way to uninstall the help+tips aaplication.